# How can I use if else to change values in some rows and columns in my data frame in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I have a data frame with 200 rows and 150 columns. Out of those columns, I wish to change the NAs of about 50 rows, and 100 columns.

Below is an example of (a small part) of my data frame:

```
    >df
       Bird  Mammal  Type
    1    NA    1     A
    2    1     0     B
    3    1     0     A
    4    0     NA    A
    5    NA    1     A
    6    0     0     B
    7    0     0     A
    8    NA    NA    A 
    9    1     1     B
    10   1     1     A
```

What I want, is to change all the NAs to 0 ONLY for type "A", but not for type "B". For type "B", I want everything to remain the same.

I have tried to do this with various ifelse options, but I think I still don't have the hang of it. Here are some of the things I've tried:

a) Subsetting only the columns as a list:

```
    try <- c(1,2)

    for(i in 1:length(try)){
    df[,try[i]] <- ifelse(df[,is.na(try[i])],0,df[,try[i]])
    }
```

b) Subsetting both rows and columns (this gave me a data frame, so off course the ifelse didn't run)

Comment: df[is.na(df$Mammal) & df$Type=="A","Mammal"]=0;df[is.na(df$Bird) & df$Type=="A","Bird "]=0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple one liner that gets exactly what you want. No loops or apply needed.

```
df[is.na(df) & df$Type=='A'] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of lapply and ifelse.
Assuming you have a vector of indices or names of the columns with the NAs stored as `cols` you can do the following:

```
df[ ,cols] <- as.data.frame(lapply(cols, 
              FUN = function(x) ifelse(df$Type == "A" & is.na(df[,x]), 0, df[, x])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `set` from `data.table`.  We are considering all the other columns except the 'Type' column.  The `set` option is fast.  Also, this is changing the values in the column without converting to a logical matrix.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), 'Type')
for(j in nm1){
  set(df, i= which(is.na(df[[j]]) & df$Type=='A'), j=j, value=0)
}
```